# Debugging crashes on non-market app

Tags: android, crash

I'm aware the Play Store will let you know of any crashes your app has. But how do you read the crash logs when you app is distributed by any other way? I read inside `/data/tombstone` might be files with related crashes, but on my **Nexus 4** there is nothing in the `/data/` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But how do you read the crash logs when you app is distributed by any other way?

Integrate one of any number of crash reporting solutions, whether it be open source ones like [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) or commercial ones like [Crashlytics](https://crashlytics.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use raygun.io as it seems to be a complete solution.